# Pickle data was truncated when importing more than one list

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pickle, python-sockets

I'm trying to build a client-server application for a college project, and the main goal is to have a client machine make a request to get some information from a server machine, such as cpu usage, memory usage, files and directories and such, and send them back to the client machine to read (I'm also presenting these information graphically in pygame).
Whenever I try to use pickle.load more than once, I get this error on the client side:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(...)", line 23, in <module>
    lista = pickle.loads(caminho)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

Does anyone know to use load information from server more than once? I'd really appreciate any kind of help!

Server side:

```
import socket, psutil, pickle, os, time, datetime, cpuinfo


def mostra_uso_cpu_e_ram(socket_cliente):
    info1 =('Usuario solicitou Informações de uso de processamento e Memória')
    resposta = []
    resposta.append(psutil.cpu_percent())
    resposta.append(cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand'])
    resposta.append(cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['arch'])
    resposta.append(cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['bits'])
    resposta.append(cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['hz_actual'])
    resposta.append(psutil.cpu_freq()[0])
    resposta.append(psutil.disk_usage('/')[3])
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    mem_percent = mem.used/mem.total
    resposta.append(mem_percent)
    bytes_resp = pickle.dumps(resposta)
    socket_cliente.send(bytes_resp)
    print(info1)


def arquivos_diretorios(socket_cliente):
    info2 = ('\nUsuario solicitou Informações sobre arquivos e diretórios')
    info2 += ('\n\n-------------------------------------------------------\n\n INFORMAÇÕES SOBRE DIRETÓRIOS E ARQUIVOS\n')
    socket_cliente.send(info2.encode('utf-8'))
    
    lista_send = []
    caminho = os.getcwd()
    lista_send.append(caminho)
    caminho = pickle.dumps(lista_send)
    socket_cliente.send(caminho)
    
    lista_arquivos = []
    for a in os.listdir("."):
        if os.path.isdir(a):
            pathname = 'd %s' % a
            lista_arquivos.append(pathname)
            statinfo = os.stat(a)
            data_criacao = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_ctime)
            data_acesso = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_atime)
            data_modificacao = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_mtime)
            size = os.path.getsize(a)
            criacao = 'Data de Criação: {}'.format(data_criacao)
            lista_arquivos.append(criacao)
            acesso = 'Data do Acesso mais recente: {}'.format(data_acesso)
            lista_arquivos.append(acesso)
            modificacao = 'Data da última modificação: {}'.format(data_modificacao)
            lista_arquivos.append(modificacao)
            tamanho = 'Tamanho do diretório em bytes: {}'.format(size)
            lista_arquivos.append(tamanho)
        elif os.path.isfile(a):
            pathname = '- %s' % a
            lista_arquivos.append(pathname)
            statinfo = os.stat(a)
            data_criacao = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_ctime)
            data_acesso = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_atime)
            data_modificacao = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_mtime)
            size = statinfo.st_size
            criacao = 'Data de Criação: {}'.format(data_criacao)
            lista_arquivos.append(criacao)
            acesso = 'Data do Acesso mais recente: {}'.format(data_acesso)
            lista_arquivos.append(acesso)
            modificacao = 'Data da última modificação: {}'.format(data_modificacao)
            lista_arquivos.append(modificacao)
            tamanho = 'Tamanho do arquivo em bytes: {}'.format(size)
            lista_arquivos.append(tamanho)
    arq_dir = pickle.dumps(lista_arquivos)
    socket_cliente.send(arq_dir)

def processos_ativos(socket_cliente):
    info3 = ('\nUsuario solicitou Informações sobre processos ativos')
    info3 += ('\n\n-------------------------------------------------------\n\n INFORMAÇÕES SOBRE PROCESSOS EM ANDAMENTO\n')
    info3 += ('\n\n*** Lista de processos em andamento no servidor ***\n\n')
    socket_cliente.send(info3.encode('utf-8'))
    
    listOfProcessNames = []

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():

        pInfoDict = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'cpu_percent'])

        listOfProcessNames.append(pInfoDict)

    proc_info = pickle.dumps(listOfProcessNames)
    socket_cliente.send(proc_info)

def informacoes_redes(socket_cliente):
    info4 = ('\nUsuario solicitou Informações sobre Rede')
    info4 += ('\n\n-------------------------------------------------------\n\n INFORMAÇÕES SOBRE REDE\n')
    socket_cliente.send(info4.encode('utf-8'))
    af_map = {
        socket.AF_INET: 'IPv4',
        socket.AF_INET6: 'IPv6',
        psutil.AF_LINK: 'MAC',
    }


    stats = psutil.net_if_stats()
    io_counters = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
    lista_redes = []
    for nic, addrs in psutil.net_if_addrs().items():
        rede = '%s:' % (nic)
        lista_redes.append(rede)
        for addr in addrs:
            rede1 = '    %-4s' % af_map.get(addr.family, addr.family)
            lista_redes.append(rede1)
            rede2 = ' address   : %s' % addr.address
            lista_redes.append(rede2)
            if addr.broadcast:
                rede3 = '         broadcast : %s' % addr.broadcast
                lista_redes.append(rede3)
            if addr.netmask:
                rede4 = '         netmask   : %s' % addr.netmask
                lista_redes.append(rede4)
            if addr.ptp:
                rede5 = '      p2p       : %s' % addr.ptp
                lista_redes.append(rede5)
        #print("")
    rede_info = pickle.dumps(lista_redes)
    socket_cliente.send(rede_info)

def sair_da_conexao(socket_cliente):
    info = ('Conexão Encerrada!')
    socket_cliente.send(info.encode('utf-8'))
    print("Fechando Conexão...")
    socket_cliente.close()

socket_servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
porta = 9999
socket_servidor.bind((host, porta))
socket_servidor.listen()
print("Servidor", host, "esperando conexão na porta", porta)
(socket_cliente,addr) = socket_servidor.accept()
print("Conectado a:", str(addr))

while True:
    mostra_uso_cpu_e_ram(socket_cliente)
    arquivos_diretorios(socket_cliente)
    processos_ativos(socket_cliente)
    informacoes_redes(socket_cliente)
    sair_da_conexao(socket_cliente)
```

Client side:

```
import socket, time, pickle

import pygame

def imprime(l):
    texto = ''
    for i in l:
        texto = texto + '\n' + '{:>20}'.format(i)
    print(texto)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9999))


bytes_resp = s.recv(1024)
lista = pickle.loads(bytes_resp)
memoria = imprime(lista)


info2 = s.recv(4000)
caminho = s.recv(4000)
arq_dir = s.recv(1000000)
lista = pickle.loads(caminho)
files_info = pickle.loads(arq_dir)

def display_slide():
    
    tela1 = True

    while tela1:
        
        tela.fill([0, 0, 0])
    
        texto1 = font.render('MENU', True, verde, preto)
        textoRect1 = texto1.get_rect()
        textoRect1.topleft=[100,25]
        tela.blit(texto1, textoRect1)
        
        textoc = font.render('1 - Uso de Processamento e Memória ', True, verde, preto)
        textoRectc = textoc.get_rect()
        textoRectc.topleft=[10,100]
        tela.blit(textoc, textoRectc)
        
        texto2 = font.render('2 - Arquivos e Diretórios ', True, verde, preto)
        textoRect2 = texto2.get_rect()
        textoRect2.topleft=[10,150]
        tela.blit(texto2, textoRect2)
        
        texto3 = font.render('3 - Processos Ativos: ', True, verde, preto)
        textoRect3 = texto3.get_rect()
        textoRect3.topleft=[10,200]
        tela.blit(texto3, textoRect3)
        
        texto4 = font.render('4 - Redes ', True, verde, preto)
        textoRect4 = texto4.get_rect()
        textoRect4.topleft=[10,250]
        tela.blit(texto4, textoRect4)
        
        texto5 = font.render('5 - Sair ', True, verde, preto)
        textoRect5 = texto5.get_rect()
        textoRect5.topleft=[10,300]
        tela.blit(texto5, textoRect5)
        
        texto6 = font.render('Selecione uma das opções do menu ou pressione seta para a direita para navegar ', True, verde, preto)
        textoRect6 = texto6.get_rect()
        textoRect6.topleft=[10,350]
        tela.blit(texto6, textoRect6)
    
        pygame.display.flip()
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    tela1 = False
                    tela2 = True
                else:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                        tela1 = False
                        tela2 = True

    while tela2:
        
        tela.fill([0, 0, 0])
        
        texto1 = font.render('Informações: '+str(memoria), True, verde, preto)
        textoRect1 = texto1.get_rect()
        textoRect1.topleft=[10,5]
        tela.blit(texto1, textoRect1)
        
        pygame.display.flip()
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    tela2 = False
                    tela1 = True
                #elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    #tela2 = False
                    #tela3 = True

pygame.init()

largura_tela = 800
altura_tela = 800
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((largura_tela, altura_tela))
background = pygame.Surface(tela.get_size())
tela.blit(background, (0,0))
pygame.display.set_caption('Monitoramento e Análise do Sistema')
tela.fill([0, 0, 0])

verde = (0, 255, 0)
preto = (0, 0, 0)
cinza = (128, 128, 128, 255)

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)

terminou = False

while not terminou:

    display_slide()
    
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.display.quit()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, my mistake, found out I was using the same variable "lista" twice. Once I took it out of the code, it worked